# How to create a matrix from an equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Let A = $(a_{ij})$ be the matrix with entries

$a_{ij} = i^2+j^2$

A is a $N\times N$ matrix

How can I construct a matrix from this equation?

Comment: Move through each entry of the matrix using a for-loop for $i$ and for-loop for $j$ (one inside the other). Then assign each entry $i^{2}+j^{2}$.

Comment: That'd be a great way to do it in Fortran; in Matlab...not so idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 1:n;
s2 = s .^ 2;
g = repmat(s2, n, 1);
a = g + g';
```

That, or something very like it, should work. Yep. I tried it. Works fine. 
Even more matlab-y (although personally I'd avoid this kind of thing):

```
s = (1:n) .^ 2;
[x,y] = meshgrid(s,s); 
a = x + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will address the slightly more general situation where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, and you can just make $M=N$ if you would like.

```
[iImg,jImg] = meshgrid( 1:N, 1:M );
A = iImg .* iImg + jImg .* jImg;
```

Or, for more efficiency,

```
[iSqImg,jSqImg] = meshgrid( (1:N).^2, (1:M).^2 );
A = iSqImg + jSqImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1:N

    for j = 1:N

      A(i,j) = i^2 + j^2

    end

end
```

Comment: For $N = 1000$, this is about twenty times slower than my second solution, and about 30 times slower than my first.  There are idioms in programming languages for a reason.

Comment: @JohnHughes yes you are correct, but for completeness I included this implementation since you already listed the other way.  For small enough N, this is completely feasible and easier to understand.

Comment: I can't agree. One might equally well argue that "Pleased to meet you" is easier to understand than "enchanté de faire votre connaissance," but that's only if you're speaking English. Back in the days of APL, you could always tell a FORTRAN programmer's APL code, because it was almost impossible to read, having been literally translated from the FORTRAN, and therefore full of loops and tests and go-tos, rather than using the vector/matrix/tensor operations that were built into APL, often as single characters. My TAs sometimes joke about "Jacket," i.e., Java code written in Racket. It's awful.

Comment: @JohnHughes noted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple code with a good performance and without `for` is:

```
N = 10; 
range = 1:N;
MI = repmat(range.', 1, N);
MJ = repmat(range, N, 1);
A = MI.^2 + MJ.^2;
```

Comment: @JohnHughes you're right. it's corrected.